# Can the scheduler or some critical kernel threads be preempted in a preemptible Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler, schedule, preemption

Can the scheduler or some critical kernel threads be preempted in a preemptible Linux kernel? What about in an interrupt handler (top half or bottom half)?

Comment: The scheduler is not a kernel task (but it manages these preemptable tasks)

Comment: So what is the scheduler? A userspace program if not kernel task?

Comment: The scheduler is an essential part of the kernel, but it is not a kernel task

Comment: Could you tell me the difference? Thanks.

Comment: You should take several hours to read some material about operating system & kernel.

Comment: I cannot find the concept "kernel task" when searching several Linux kernel books (using string matching)...

Answer (score 1):

The kernel calls [__schedule()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.7/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L3396) to do the actual context switch. It always call this with preemption disabled. You can search the callers and notice the call to `preempt_disable` before calling `__schedule`. So, it can't be preempted.

Also, an interrupt handler cannot be preempted. Preemption is disabled here. But linux kernel is preemptible which means kernel threads and other code can be preempted if it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Any kernel thread or generally speaking any portion of code can be preempted :

- By a thread of higher priority
- While not in a section protected against interrupts and preemption

So yes even the scheduler can be preempted by a hardware interrupt for instance.